# How do I loop through a file to create a series of new .docx files?

Tags: linux, cat, xargs

## Background

I have a `file` of file names like so:

```
something.txt
another.cpp
whoa.cxx
...
```

I want to create a corresponding text file for each one as such in the current directory:

```
./something.txt.docx
./another.cpp.docx
./whoa.cxx.docx
```

This should be a very simple operation...but the series of commands I am thinking of trying don't seem to make sense logically:

## Attempted solutions

1. Pipe a cat into touch : `cat file | touch <not sure what to put here>.docx`.

   a. As you can see, I am at a loss of how to append a .docx extension to each file name that I encounter, and I do not know a way to neatly do a regex append in this manner. The [touch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) man page does not seem to be helpful on this front either.
2. Pipe cat into xargs touch: `cat file | xargs -I{} touch {}.docx`

   a. My intention was to use the [-I option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to literally append .docx to get the result seen above. Below is the intended functionality of -I:

   > **-I replace-str**
   >
   > Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
   >             with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do
   >             not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
   >             newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

   This threw the error `xargs: .docx: No such file or directory`.

## Question

How do loop through a file and create corresponding .docx's for each line in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file contents are reasonably well formatted and don't have strange corner cases, you can do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  touch "$line.docx"
done < input-file-name.txt
```

I just confirmed that it works on my system.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by below command

ls -1rt | awk '{ print "touch " $0 ".docx" }' | bash